# traverse an array property in an object key

Tags: typescript

In my queue interface I have an object key, and then I check if the queue already exists and if it doesn't exist, I register my queue in my object key

interface:

```
export type IQueue = {
  name: string;
  options?: Options.AssertQueue;
  handlers?: IHandler<IMessage>[];
};
export interface IQueues {
  [name: string]: IQueue;
}
```

but I have the property of my type IQueue
handlers which is an array of my handler type, I can't imagine how I can solve this problem:
check if the handlers sent as a parameter for a function already exist in the handlers of my key, and if it does not exist it will be added:

```
  public subscribe = (data: IQueue) => {
    if (BrokerChannel.channel[data.name]) {
      const handlers = BrokerChannel.channel[data.name].handlers;
    }
    BrokerChannel.channel[data.name] = data;
  };
```

Comment: Just add a `return;` inside the `if { ... }` so if it already exists you return without adding it?

Comment: my handler is an array, and I have what is sent by parameter and what is already in the object key, basically I want to check if there is a handler that was sent by parameter that does not exist in the object key handler

Comment: I thought that maybe it's possible with reduce, but I don't know how to do it

Comment: Sorry I'm having trouble understanding. Maybe you could add some before/after examples?

Comment: basically i have two arrays i need to know which elements of the array that is as parameters are not contained in the object array BrokerChannel.channel